# Regex replace the colon in between a colon and a semi-colon

Tags: php, regex

Given a string, how can I identify the string has a colon in between a colon and a semi-colon?

For example, I want to identify that the following has a `:` in between `:` and `;`. If this is the case, I want to replace the colon in the middle.

`background-image: url('http://google.com/img.jpg');"`

I can't come up with a regex for the life of me. I can only match the whole `url('http://google.com/img.jpg')`. What regex can I use that can do this for me?

```
$pattern = ''; 

$matched = preg_replace($pattern, '|__|', $string);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/(:.*?):(.*?;)/s';
$matched = preg_replace($pattern, '$1|__|$2', $string);
```